# How is it possible to do such a derivative? $ \frac{d}{d(x+y)}\sum_{r=0}^\infty(x+y)^{\alpha +r}$

Tags: derivatives

I want to do the following derivative

$$ \frac{d}{d(x+y)}\sum_{r=0}^\infty(x+y)^{\alpha +r}$$

and I guessed I must begin from the following statement:

$$ \frac{d}{d(x+y)}=  \frac{d}{dx}\sum_{r=0}^\infty(x+y)^{\alpha +r}+ \frac{d}{dy}\sum_{r=0}^\infty(x+y)^{\alpha +r}$$

I want to know, is it right or not?

Comment: where did you see this?

Comment: For one thing $\frac{1}{a+ b}$ is **not** equal to $\frac{1}{a}+ \frac{1}{b}$ so you can't "separate" the derivative like that.  Instead, let u= x+ y so that the derivative becomes $\frac{d}{du}\sum_{r=0}^\infty u^{n+r}= \sum_{r=0}^\infty \frac{du^{n+r}}{du}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ASSUMPTION**: $\left|x+y\right| \lt 1$. 
To avoid confusion lets substitute $(x+y)=t$
Following this substitution, we have :
$$\frac{d}{dt} \sum_{r=0}^{\infty} \left(t\right)^{\alpha +r}$$ To be evaluated. 
$\sum _{r=0}^{\infty}t^{\alpha +r} $ can be written as :
$$t^{\alpha}+t^{\alpha +1}+ \cdots + t^{\alpha +n} + \cdots$$
taking $t^{\alpha}$ common from all terms:
$$t^{\alpha} (1+t+t^2+ \cdots + t^n +\cdots)$$
Applying sum of infinite geometric progression for common ratio $\in (-1,1)$ we get :
$$ t^{\alpha} \left(\frac{1}{1-t}\right)$$
$\therefore$ we have to finally evaluate :
$$\frac {d}{dt} \frac{t^{\alpha}}{1-t}$$
This can be easily evaluated by the quotient rule and we finally end up in: 
$$ \frac{\alpha t^{\alpha -1} (1-t) +t^{\alpha }}{(1-t)^2}$$

Comment: Thanks sai-kartik, your comment is so useful but the summation is vanished in your method while i don't want it.

Comment: I don't think the derivative will be easy to simply without resolving the summation first..I have made the assumption that $|x+y| \lt 1$ because if it wasn't, the summation would become infinite and differentiation would not be possible

Answer (score 0):

No, your first attempt is not correct. (Or rather, I'd be astonished if it were correct; I haven't actually proved it incorrect.)

Hint: substitute $z = x + y$ to avoid confusion.

Comment: Dear Patrick, thanks a lot for your attention.